# How to remove cam lock with screw stuck inside it?

Tags: repair, screws, self-assembly-furniture

I'm trying to reassemble this furniture but it has screw stuck inside a cam screw:

[image: Screw stuck inside cam screw]

[image: Screw stuck inside cam screw]

How do I remove the cam screw or the screw? I suppose the cam screw comes out first?

Answer (score 1):

turn the cam lock till this arrow points to directly to the screw, than pull the screw out –

[image: point]

Comment: Thank you. I tried pulling it out but it won't fully come out - is there an easy way to take the cam screw out other than drilling another screw into it?

Comment: @mac considering you damaged the board, there was some force on the screw. Use players to get it out AFTER you aligned the cam

Comment: @Mac which way are you trying to turn the cam lock to undo it? you should be turning it counter-clockwise (against the direction of the white arrow), until the other small arrow lines up with the screw - so it needs to go almost a full circle.

Comment: Once you've correctly aligned the cam lock, a sharp tap on the board behind it should eject it. Or a strong magnet

Comment: You need to align the cam as indicated, but since you yanked the other board off the screw, it may have jammed the screw head in the cam. So try gently tapping the screw back toward the cam and see if that loosens things up enough to pry the cam out of the bore.